# Windows 10 Login requires Alt-Tab from keyboard

Tags: windows-10

Background: In Windows 7&8, I could just start typing my password on the login screen and it would go in the box with no mouse click required.

Since upgrading to Windows 10, I have to click in the login box, or press Alt-Tab on the keyboard to start typing my password.  I've tried other keyboard combinations (i.e. Tab, CTRL+Tab) but only Alt-Tab works.

Some possible factors:

- I use a laptop (Dell Latitude E5570).
- I keep the lid closed and have a USB 3.0 docking station (Toshiba Dynadock U3.0).
- I have tested with two laptops and had the same results.
- The computer is a member of a domain, but I have no Group Policy settings related to login.
- I'm using a Logitech k750 Keyboard.

Any suggestions or troubleshooting tips would be welcome.  I'm an IT guy and I'm usually capable of fixing minor issues like this, but this one has me stumped.

Comment: `Escape` also works, but that's probably not what you had in mind...

Comment: I think they default to the user list, if I press enter while the screen is loading the last user will be selected (and logged in if they have no password, ugh).